# How to create Calendar Events to generate notifications for taking medications

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I like to create calendar events with notifications to assist me in taking medications sometimes when the medication regimen gets complicated.  I found this application to be quite useful to me and thought perhaps others might like to use such a script.  It uses an array of objects to process the medication title, the hours it must be taken and the notifications that you require.

Admittedly, I used hours only rather than hours and minutes.  It seemed like a useful simplification to me.

Here's the code:

```
function createMyEvents() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendar id");
  const tA = [{ title: "Take Med1", hours: [6, 12, 18, 23], nots: [10, 30] }, { title: "Take Med2", hours: [8, 20], nots: [10, 30] }];
  //add to calendar for the following offset days
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6].forEach(offset => {
    let dt = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + offset);
    tA.forEach(obj => {
      //using the hours array to create events for each day 
      obj.hours.forEach(h => {
        let st = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), h)
        let et = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), h + 1);
        let event = cal.createEvent(obj.title, st, et)
        obj.nots.forEach(m => {
          event.addPopupReminder(m);//notifications for each event
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Current Answer:

- Uses a control sheet to set up the parameters for each event creation sequence which also stores the event id's created which makes it possible to also delete the events by iterating through the list.

Code:

```
function makeEventArray(start = 9, end = 12, offA = '') {
  if (!offA) {
    const arr = [...Array.from(new Array(end - start + 1).keys(), x => start + x)];
    //Logger.log(arr);
    return arr;
  } else {
    return offA;
  }
}

function createMyEventsFromList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('MakeEvents');
  const shsr = 3;
  let d = new Date();
  sh.getRange("C1").setValue(d).setNumberFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
  sh.getRange("E1").setValue(d).setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  const vs = sh.getRange(shsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r,i) => {r[9] = i + shsr;return r; }).filter(r => r[0] == true).filter(e => e);
  if (vs && vs.length > 0) {
    ss.toast('Process Running','Creating Events',300)
    vs.forEach(r => {
      let idA = [];
      let title = r[1];
      let hours;
      if (~r[2].toString().indexOf(',')) {
        hours = r[2].toString().split(',').map(e => Number(e));
      } else {
        hours = [r[2]];
      }
      let nots;
      if (~r[3].toString().indexOf(",")) {
        nots = r[3].toString().split(',').map(e => Number(e));
      } else {
        nots = [r[3]];
      }
      let desc = r[4];
      let start = r[5];
      let end = r[6];
      let offA;
      if (r[7] && r[7].toString().length > 0) {
        if (r[7].toString().includes(',')) {
          offA = r[7].toString().split(',').map(e => Number(e));
        } else {
          offA = [r[7]];
        }
      }
      const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("q289qp9augtnshkn70dkibcc54@group.calendar.google.com");
      const tob = { start: start, end: end, offA: offA, desc: desc, tA: [{ title: title, hours: hours, nots: nots }] };
      makeEventArray(tob.start, tob.end, tob.offA).forEach(offset => {
        let dt = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + offset);
        tob.tA.forEach(obj => {
          obj.hours.forEach(h => {
            let st = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), h)
            let et = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), h + 1);
            let event = cal.createEvent(obj.title, st, et);;
            if (event) {
              event.setDescription(tob.desc);
              idA.push(event.getId())
            }
            if (event && obj.nots && obj.nots.length > 0) {
              obj.nots.forEach(m => {
                event.addPopupReminder(m);
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
      sh.getRange(r[9],9,1,2).setValues([[idA.join(', '),r[9]]])
    });
    ss.toast('Process Complete','Creating Events',15);
  }
}

function deleteEventsFromList() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("q289qp9augtnshkn70dkibcc54@group.calendar.google.com");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('MakeEvents');
  const shsr = 3;
  const vs = sh.getRange(shsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - shsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r,i) => {r[9] = i + shsr;return r; }).filter(r => r[0] == true).filter(e => e);
  ss.toast('Process Running','Deleeting Events',180)
  vs.forEach(r => {
    r[8].toString().split(', ').forEach(id => {
      cal.getEventById(id).deleteEvent();
    });
    sh.getRange(r[9],9,1,2).clearContent();
  });
  ss.toast('Process Complete','Deleeting Events');
}
```

Image of Sheet:

[image]

Changed

```
const shsr = 3;
let d = new Date();
```

to this to allow starting date selection:

```
const shsr = 3;
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Get StartDate","yyyy/M/d",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var t = r.getResponseText().split('/');
  } else {
    ss.toast("Making Events","Cancelled Operation by User",5)
    return;
  }
  let d = new Date(t[0],Number(t[1]) - 1,t[2]);
```